# Update value in one table based on value of another table

Tags: postgresql

I would like to compare two tables, t1 & t2, and change the value of a columns row value in t1 based on the condition of a column in t2.

t1:

| fid | vul | agg_cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.6 | 1400 |
| 2 | 0.5 | 1300 |
| 3 | 0.8 | 1200 |

t2:

| fid | vul | agg_cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2 | 200 |
| 2 | 0.5 | 2000 |
| 3 | 0.8 | 450 |

desired outcome of t1:

| fid | vul | agg_cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.0 | 1400 |
| 2 | 0.5 | 1300 |
| 3 | 1.0 | 1200 |

I have used this query but it makes the wrong changes:

```
UPDATE t1 
SET vul = 1.0
FROM t2
WHERE t1.agg_cost > t2.agg_cost;
```

& the inner join gives me table name t1 specified more than once.

```
UPDATE t1 
SET vul = 1  
FROM t1  
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.fid = t2.fid 
WHERE t1.agg_cost > t2.agg_cost;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it right, you want to update t1 if there exist a row in t2 with the same fid and a bigger agg_cost

```
UPDATE t1 
    SET vul = 1  
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t2 
    WHERE t1.fid = t2.fid 
      AND t1.agg_cost > t2.agg_cost
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE t1 
   SET vul = 1
 WHERE fid IN (SELECT t2.fid 
                    FROM t2
                    WHERE t1.agg_cost > t2.agg_cost);
```